# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de una tablas navegando en una paginación?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo una tabla donde al seleccionar el checkbox obtengo los datos de las columnas y el estatus del checkbox, los agrego a un arreglo para enviarlos al contralor.

El problema es que al ponerle paginación, cuando selecciono cualquier checkbox de cualquier pagina, al seleccinar un boton de aceptar solo obtiene los primeros checkbox de la pagina en donde me encuentro, ejemplo: si al seleccionar el boton de aceptar me encuentro en la pagina 5 solo toma esos checkbox seleccionados de la pagina 5, los demas checkbox seleccionados de otras paginas no los agrega al arreglo.

¿Hay alguna forma de que se vayan agregando los datos y los checkbox seleccionados u otra forma para enviarlos?

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="tblRep">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                       <th>Seleccion</th>
                       <th>Numero</th>
                       <th>Cliente</th>
                       <th>Fecha</th>
                       <th>Intereses</th>
                       <th>Iva</th>
                       <th>Retención</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                         @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                   {

                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="@Model[i].check" multiple id="check_@(i)" name="check" />
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].c_numero)
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].razon)
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].f_fecha)
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].n_tabintereses)
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].n_tabiva)
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].n_monto_ret)
                           </td>       
                       </tr>

                   }

                </tbody>
            </table>

          <div class="box-footer">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnAceppt" value="Aceptar" />               
        </div>
```

Este es el script que le da la funcionalidad a la tabla para la paginación, filtros entre otros.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
  $(function () {
      $('#tblRep').dataTable({
      'paging': true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : true,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  })
    </script>
```

Este script al seleccionar un boton obtiene los checkbox seleccionados, los agrega a un arreglo y lo envia por ajax al controlador.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <script>

        $('#btnAceppt').click(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var arr2 = [];

                $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {

                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        var idCheck = $(this).attr("id");
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var numero = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
                        var c_numero = numero.trim(); //Numero
                        var cliente = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
                        var c_cliente = cliente.trim(); //Cliente
                        var intereses = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
                        var n_tabintereses = intereses.trim(); //Intereses
                        var iva = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(5)').text();
                        var n_tabiva = iva.trim(); //Iva                            
                       

                        arr2.push(c_numero + '|' + c_cliente + '|' + n_tabnumero + '|' + n_tabiva)
                    }

                })
                
               var uri = '@Url.Action("Invoice", "Contract")';
                var arr = arr2;
                $.ajax({
                    url: uri,
                    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json'
                });

        })
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: te recomiendo leerte la librería, es muy extensa y detallada [enlace](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/multi.html) en esta parte explican lo que tu quieres lograr, puedes complementarlo de lo que te respondieron abajo, solo necesitas agregar el multi select

Answer (score 0):

*DataTables* controla internamente la información y solo agrega en el DOM las filas correspondientes a cada página; no puedes seleccionar filas de diferentes páginas porque, técnicamente, no existen.

Debes usar la extensión [select](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/select.html) y hacer algunas adaptaciones para [obtener](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html) los elementos seleccionados. El único problema con esto es que necesitas mantener presionada la tecla [CTRL] para seleccionar varias filas y habría que buscar la forma de simplificar para hacerlo con un simple clic.

Por cierto, es opcional incluir el botón en la tabla, puedes tenerlo aparte, esto es solo un ejemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        pageLength: 4,
        // Permitir seleccionar
        select: true,
        // Primera columna agrega un selector
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        // Configuración del selector
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        // Agregar botón para obtener todos los marcados
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Obtener marcados',
                action: function () {
                    let rowsData = table.rows({ selected: true }).data();
                    for(let i = 0; i < rowsData.length; i++) {
                        // Aquí puedes obtener los datos de cada fila (no HTML)
                        console.log(rowsData[i]);
                        // Nombre: rowData[i][1]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```